# $R^2$ is too high- reasons?

Tags: r-squared, misspecification

What are the reasons of too high values of $R^2$? I only know that its value increases when the number of independent variables increases. What are the other factors?

Comment: Given that in some situations $R^2$ very close to 1 are perfectly plausible, what is the basis on which you declare that it's "too high"? What makes a particular $R^2$ implausible?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment describing your problem in response to @PsychometStats, it appears you are regressing a variable that tends to increase over time - population - on a variable that tends to increase over time - GDP, and possibly on others.   This will cause high $R^2$ values regardless of whether there is any real relationship between the target variable and the regressors.

The general term relating to this phenomenon is *cointegration*; see the answers to the Stackexchange question [Linear regression of nonstationary variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118296/linear-regression-of-nonstationary-variables/169353#169353) for some explanation or the Wikipedia page https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cointegration (probably best to start the latter at the "History" section; the fourth paragraph has a particularly appropriate example.)  It is very common with basic economic series, and this link https://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/finmath09/Cointegration.pdf contains an explanation oriented towards people who work with these series.

Note that two variables don't have to be cointegrated in order for there to be a spurious regression effect; I highlight cointegration because that appears often in economic time series.

For a straightforward example, consider regressing annual GDP from 2002 through last year against a single regressor comprised of my daughter's age plus the number of trips she took to Germany in that year, with a trip counted double if she travelled alone:

[image]

Here's the regression (in R):

```
> summary(lm(gdp~age))

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 11.05660    0.22344   49.48  < 2e-16 ***
age          0.46161    0.01982   23.29 9.06e-14 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4797 on 16 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9713,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9695 
F-statistic: 542.3 on 1 and 16 DF,  p-value: 9.056e-14
```

That's a pretty impressive $R^2$ by most standards, but... the regression is still meaningless.

If we instead try to see if we can explain *changes* in annual GDP by *changes* in the modified age variable, we get:

```
> summary(lm(diff(gdp)~diff(age)))

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  0.61327    0.33390   1.837   0.0862 .
diff(age)   -0.09082    0.26495  -0.343   0.7365  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.6361 on 15 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.007772,  Adjusted R-squared:  -0.05838 
F-statistic: 0.1175 on 1 and 15 DF,  p-value: 0.7365
```

which, fortunately for economic forecasters everywhere, indicates that the modified age variable does not help us predict year-over-year changes in GDP.

For how to address this problem, I recommend doing some research on cointegration; the Wikipedia page linked to above is not a bad place to start, nor is the linked PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I would check for very highly correlated variables. This is known as multicollinearity, which may substantially overinflate your beta coefficients. Consequently, your $R^2$ may be unreasonably high. If that is the case, remove one of such variables and check if $R^2$ decreases.

> **EDIT: 
>   For clarification purposes: The above implied to check if the DV itself was very highly correlated with one of the predictors.**

Comment: I checked a multicollinearity and everything is OK.

Comment: @lost6996 it'd be useful if you posted your model and provided some information on it

Comment: I have 25 observations. I model GDP by population, unemployment and secondary enrollment. Unemployment rate and population size are significant.

Comment: @los6996 your regression is very underpowered. Most likely very small sample size is causing problems

Comment: @los6996 note R^2=1 - (residual sum of squares)/(total sum of squares). So to get very high R^2 you need a very small value in the division part. This can happen when residual sum of squares is very low but total sum of squares is very high. So you divide for example 5/100 = .05. Then R^2 is 1-.05=.95 which is very high. This is the intuition for you.

Comment: Multicollinearity of the regressors does not cause a high $R^2$; to see this, consider the limiting case of perfect multicollinearity, in which case, say, 10 regressors may have the explanatory power of just one or two of the regressors and the remaining eight or nine regressors contribute nothing to the regression.

Comment: @jbowman (+1) I agree with that. However, I was implying to check if there was a very high correlation between the DV itself (the GDP) and one of the predictors.

Comment: Ah, fair point.  Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @jbowman I guess I should have made it clearer at first, but I have added the clarification to the original post